# Index on Sharepoint Linked table

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access 2010 and I already have sharepoint linked table created in the database.

I wanted to know how i can create indexes on this linked table. When i am going to design view of linked table and clicking on indexes cloumn getting message like this property can not be modified in linked table.

I am actually trying to run one query on top of linked table and its taking very time to return resutls when doing Analyze performance then getting message of creating indexes on few fields of linked table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can most certainly create and set the indexes from Access with a linked table to SharePoint.

The way you do this is bring up the linked table in table view (not design view). Then in the ribbon you click on the index button. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

You can also of course if you want bring up the table on the SharePoint site and also add the index that way.

Note that you can also use this layout mode to add new columns to the SharePoint tables from Access.

Comment: Hi Albert..But fields section is grayed out for me..any idea how i can activate it..pls see below post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850080/table-view-sharepoint-list

Comment: So I am in Access 2007 but am not seeing a "table view".  I have a "datasheet view" ... but under my "table tools" section of the ribbon it just has "datasheet" and not "fields".  I must be looking at something wrong.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not create indexes on linked tables in MS Access. You will need to either create new indexes in sharepoint or import the data from your linked table and create an index on that.

Comment: How i can improt data from linked table..I mean create table on top of linked table..I am very new to access database

Comment: If you want to do this as a one off right click on the link table, click copy and then in the tables area right click and paste. Alternativly create a query that selects the data and then from the query menu choose "Make Table Query" - this will create your first table.

Comment: Thanks Spencer..But i guess this table will require manual refresh right? it won't pick up latest data from sharepoint correct?

Comment: That would depend on the data. We have some table here that are coppied locally each time MS Access is opened. In simple terms we created an autoexec macro which runs the queries at startup to copy the data. When you get more farmilliar with Access VBA you will be able to write code that does that for you.

Comment: This is 100% wrong - you can most certanly create indexes from Access

Comment: The index is not on the linked table - it is a local index - which helps but is not as fast as using a linked table with the correct index. A SQLStatistics call would need to be made by MS Access each time the index was used to make sure the local copy matched the server data.

Comment: We not talking about a local index here. We are talking about a linked table sitting on SharePoint.  >>A SQLStatistics call would need to be made>> No SQL server here. We are connecting to a table (called a list) on SharePoint. There are no SQL stats or SQL system involved for this linked table. Access connects to SharePoint by using a Web Service and web service calls (this is not ODBC). So when you set an index as my screen shot shows that index is being created SERVER SIDE ON SharePoint. In fact you can even add new columns and again that column is created server side on SharePoint.