# table view sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

Need your inputs on below query-

after opening share point linked table in table view, fields section is grayed out for me..As mentioned in the below post, I want to set index on columns of sharepoint linked list ..How i can activate this section?

appreciate your inputs..

This is related to below post

[Index on Sharepoint Linked table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647844/index-on-sharepoint-linked-table)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, everything going to be greyed out if your cursor in the ID column since there nothing you can change in the required auto number ID column. If you move your cursor into other columns, then the options on the ribbon should un-grey and become enabled.

I suppose the above is a long shot and I assume you moved the cursor out of the ID column or at least clicked on the column you want to make changes to. So your picture as you show is correct since your cursor is placed in the ID column of which as noted you cannot change anything about that ID column anyway.

Comment: Sorry Albert..But even though moving cursor to other cloumns the options on ribbon is still grayed out..is there any speical permission required to modify linked list?